# How to query JSON data from list using C# UWP

Tags: c#, json, uwp, json.net

```
 string Categoriesjson = @"[
                       {
                        'cat_id' : 1,
                         'name': 'HTML',
                         'desc': 'WebDesign',
                         'img': 'Assets/sawirada/html-flat.png',
                       }];
```

I have this JSON data i Converted to a list,
I Want to Pass the Category id to a courses page and list the courses that match this category Id using LINQ.

```
 string Coursesjson = @"[
                       {
                         'id'  : 1,
                         'cat_id' : '2',
                         'name': 'Learn HTML',
                         'date': '2017-10-19',
                         'img': 'Assets/sawirada/phpmysql.jpg',
                       }];
```

Comment: Can you show your code where you've converted to a list?

Answer (score 1):

[Deserialize](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/DeserializeCollection.htm) the Coursejson to a list, and use LINQ to get the matching courses:

```
var passedCatId = 1;
List<Course> allCourses = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Course>>(Coursejson);

List<Course>filteredCourses = allCourses.Where(c => c.cat_id == passedCatId).ToList();
```